# Enable jupyter widgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The jupyter widgets exension is not rendering the ui items. Have tried updating the client and enabling widgetsnbextension but code below :

```
!pip install --upgrade jupyter_core jupyter_client
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension

from IPython.display import display
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(button)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    print("Button clicked.")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

renders :

```
Requirement already up-to-date: jupyter_core in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: jupyter_client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: traitlets in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jupyter_core)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jupyter_client)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyzmq>=13 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jupyter_client)
Requirement already up-to-date: tornado>=4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jupyter_client)
Requirement already up-to-date: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets->jupyter_core)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets->jupyter_core)
Requirement already up-to-date: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets->jupyter_core)
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython-genutils in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets->jupyter_core)
Requirement already up-to-date: singledispatch in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado>=4.1->jupyter_client)
Requirement already up-to-date: futures in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado>=4.1->jupyter_client)
Requirement already up-to-date: backports-abc>=0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado>=4.1->jupyter_client)
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK
Button(description='Click Me!', style=ButtonStyle())
```

The text :

```
Button(description='Click Me!', style=ButtonStyle())
```

is rendered instead of a UI button

Is another library required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html :

> Question: When I display a widget or interact, I just see some text,
>   such as IntSlider(value=0) or interactive(children=(IntSlider(value=0,
>   description='x', max=1), Output()),
>   _dom_classes=('widget-interact',)). What is wrong?
>
> Answer: A text representation of the widget is printed if the widget
>   control is not available. It may mean the widget JavaScript is still
>   loading. If the message persists in the Jupyter Notebook or
>   JupyterLab, it likely means that the widgets JavaScript library is
>   either not installed or not enabled. See the installation instructions
>   above for setup instructions.

Page refresh fixed issue for me. I think installs referred to in my question were still required.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to run again the cells in the jupyter notebook. In the tab **Widgets**, selecting **Save Notebook Widgets State** should render the widgets everytime you open the notebook again, without having to re run it.